# Windows CE7 | Move and replace directory from the command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-ce

I'm trying to write a batch file that should copy a directory from a USB stick and place it in another folder on the hard disk (if the folder already exists, the new one should replace it).

Currently I'm trying something like this:

```
COPY "\Hard Disk2\sourceFolder" "\Hard Disk\targetFolder"
```

which doesn't copy any the "sourceFolder" or any subfolders.

I want to move **everything** (including folders) from my sourceFolder to my targetFolder.

Anyone knows how to do this?

For a list of available commands in Windows CE 7, please see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a57Rk.png).

More information about the commands: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee505427(v=winembedded.60).aspx

**Note:**
I don't think XCOPY or ROBOCOPY works in CE. I've tried both, but I just get the following error:

```
"Cannot execute ROBOCOPY.exe / XCOPY.exe".
```

Comment: Yeah, I get the following error:

Hard: "File not found".

Comment: First one gave me the following error:

COPY: Cannot form path from \\Hard. Name too long of malformed.

Second one gave me the following error:

COPY: Cannot form path from \\Hard/. Name too long of malformed.

Comment: It doesn't work either. "File not found"..

Comment: Thank you very much for trying!

Comment: WC. I didn't know that it's not working directly! I think you need to write some script for copying recursively, as suggested by Nicolas..

Comment: I'll work on a C# application for moving files in CE :-).

Comment: @GNKeshava I found a C# application that does pretty much what I want and I've written it for framework 3.5 (like in my CE), but when I try running it on my CE device I just get an exception because of the source and destination folders. 


I'm writing it like this in c#:  DirectoryCopy(@"\\Hard Disk2\BootFastBlink", @"\\\Hard Disk\\SubFolder1\SubFolder2", true);

It doesn't work, and none of the other variations that I've tried work.

About the folder names:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Command prompt for Windows Embedded Compact 7 is very limited and is not intend to be used on a final product, but as a tool for the firmware development and tuning. So the option that you are looking is not available and therefore, you will probably have to develop your own version of the XCopy command.